# Incrementation in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, increment

Before this gets flagged, let me admit that it is fairly similar to a question I asked a couple days ago, about a couple of other issues, but after using answers for both of the problems I was having, I am now running into another issue. Also, not sure that the title actually fits the problem I'm having, but it seems like it could be an issue of how the code is ordered in the program.

The eventual goal of this program is to calculate how many calories would be in a recipe based on ingredients added to a Recipe list box from an Ingredients list box, and the quantities of each selected ingredient. I am also supposed to perform a couple of different tests to prevent the program from crashing.

1. If the quantity text box is left empty, the program is supposed to default to adding 1 of that selected ingredient.
2. If anything other than a number is entered into the text box, the program is supposed to display a message box asking the user to please enter a numeric quantity.

My main problem now is that no matter how I try to tweak the code to make it work, I cannot get the TotalCalories to increment, so it keeps giving me a value of 0 as the answer. I am kind of on a time crunch, so if it's at all possible to fix this without having to re-write a big portion of the code I already have, that'd be great.

Here's the code I have written

```
Public Class Form1

    Private TotalCalories As Integer = 0

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim i As Integer = lstIngredients.SelectedIndex
        Dim Quantity As Double
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0

        If Trim(txtQuantity.Text) = "" Then
            Quantity = 1
        Else
            Quantity = Me.txtQuantity.Text
        End If

        If IsNumeric(txtQuantity.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("The quantity entered is not numeric. Please add a numeric quantity.")
        End If

        If intCount < Quantity Then
            lstRecipe.Items.Add(Quantity & " " & lstIngredients.Text)
            intCount += 1
        End If

        If lstRecipe.Text = "Eggs(each)" Then
            TotalCalories += Quantity * 72
        ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Flour(cups)" Then
            TotalCalories += Quantity * 455
        ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Milk(cups)" Then
            TotalCalories += Quantity * 86
        ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Sugar(cups)" Then
            TotalCalories += Quantity * 774
        ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Butter(tablespoons)" Then
            TotalCalories += Quantity * 102
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        lstRecipe.Items.Clear()
        txtQuantity.Clear()
        txtAnswer.Clear()
        TotalCalories = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        txtAnswer.Text = TotalCalories

    End Sub
End Class
```

I've also tried this using
         If lstRecipe.text= (Quantity & " " & "Eggs" & " " "(each)") Then
        ...
But that didn't work either.

Comment: Inside the `If IsNumeric(txtQuantity.Text) = False Then` block, after the `MessageBox.Show` line, put on the next line `Exit Sub`.

Comment: `intCount` doesnt really do anything here, `intCount < Quantity` will always be true because `intCount` starts as 0 every button click.  You are also probably not getting the right calorie count yet

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did fix the initial problem of the message box showing up when the quantity box was left empty thanks to a combination of the comments and the answer below. I see what you mean @Plutonix, I misread the instructions when I first began working on this and thought we were supposed to add the item to the list a certain number of times based on what was entered in quantity, like if they'd selected eggs, and put a quantity of 3, I had it adding eggs three times rather than "3 eggs" as it is written now. So thanks for pointing out that I no longer need the counter.

Comment: And you are right, the calorie counter is still always just giving me "0" in the txtAnswer box, any suggestions on how to make it actually work?

Comment: set a breakpoint on `lstRecipe.Items.Add` then step thru the long IF block - you'll see none of them or the wrong one is evaluated. then look up what the  ListBox.Text property returns

Comment: Not related to your question, but you really should have used `Select Case` instead of all of the `If-ElseIf` you have going on there...

Comment: @DouglasBarbin, I was going to go back and do that, we just covered Select Case in class yesterday, but I'm kind of pressed for time, so think for this program I'm just gonna leave it alone since our professor said he'd accept either way. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `txtQuantity` is empty then you have the `Quantity` variable set to 1, else try to parse the value typed and return if it is not a number. Also use all integers for calcs or, if a decimal value is allowed, then use a double also for the `TotalCalories` variable.

Still it is not clear what you want to do if the user types a zero in the textbox

```
Private TotalCalories As Double = 0

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim i As Integer = lstIngredients.SelectedIndex
    Dim Quantity As Double
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0

    If Trim(txtQuantity.Text) = "" Then
        Quantity = 1
    Else if Not Double.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text, Quantity)
        MessageBox.Show("The quantity entered is not numeric. Please add a numeric quantity.")
        Return ' or Exit Sub
    End If

    If intCount < Quantity Then
        lstRecipe.Items.Add(Quantity & " " & lstIngredients.Text)
        intCount += 1
    End If

    If lstRecipe.Text = "Eggs(each)" Then
        TotalCalories += (Quantity * 72)
    ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Flour(cups)" Then
        TotalCalories += (Quantity * 455)
    ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Milk(cups)" Then
        TotalCalories += (Quantity * 86)
    ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Sugar(cups)" Then
        TotalCalories += (Quantity * 774)
    ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Butter(tablespoons)" Then
        TotalCalories += (Quantity * 102)
    End If
End Sub
```

However I think you need to check against the `lstIngredients` instead

```
    If lstIngredients.Text = "Eggs(each)" Then
      ....
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed my problem! Now the only issue I'm having is that the calorie counter isn't actually calculating anything. The only answer that pops up is 0. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that none of your tests result in a true condition and thus the TotalCalories is never incrementend. If all of your items in the listRecipe are as the one that you are adding then every item is something like `Number Name_of_ingredient` and you can't match anything. Did you want to check against the `lstIngredients` instead?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. The whole point behind the program is to have the user add the items from the lstIngredients to lstRecipe and input the quantity in the text box, and calculate the calories based on what items and quantities of each are in the lstRecipe box. So would I need to write it as something like If lstRecipe.text= Quantity + "Eggs(each)" Then... ?

Comment: I have seen your comments just now, I was suggesting to change your test from `if lstRecipe.Text = "Eggs(each)" Then` to `if lstIngredients.Text = "Eggs(each)" then` and so on for all the other tests because it seems that it is the lstIngredients that contains the text string used to decide what multiplication to execute